# How to install AFNI? "unable to locate package libXp"

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to follow some instructions given to me for downloading AFNI on ubuntu.  The first thing it tells me to do in the terminal is:

```
sudo yum install libXp tcsh
sudo yum install PyQt4 R
```

but it says `yum: command not found`.  So I found, online, this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libXp tcsh
```

but it tells me `E: unable to locate package libXp`

also, for PyQt4 and for R

I read online to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it still doesn't work.  I read other things about changing sources.list file, but I'm not understanding what I should change in this file.  How do I get this to work?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install AFNI you shall install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libxp6 tcsh python-qt4 r-base
```

the libXp package is called `libxp6` in Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu , packages can be installed with `apt-get` and not with `yum`.

you can install package with

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

for your case , The proper command is to install is

```
sudo apt-get install libxp tcsh
```

and its not libXp.